# Speech Recognition in my local language using CMUSphinx (Java)

Tags: java, cmusphinx, jsapi

I want to develop speech recognition engine in my local language ***Sindhi*** (*Right to Left* - Characters Like as *Arabic* Script, much similar alphabet as that of *Arabic* or *Farsi*). I've tried demos of Sphinx4 but how can i build and add language models to it ?

Comment: Hi Mr SarfarazAli. Did you find out or do Persian pocket sphinix  at all?i want to start it but before starting i prefer to know  about its background. iam so gla that you want to do it.

Comment: i ve done a little bit and i m doing on it still..

Comment: vow! i'm so glad!i hope best wishes for you! did you follow CMU-web site processes? i decided to do it, but unfortunatlly i couldn't work with English one. i don't know where i should define keyword? *http://stackoverflow.com/q/37225500/4568864*   -  At all, do you want to upload your result as specific project in GitHub?